# How to "docker load" multiple images at once?

Tags: bash, docker

All,
Let's say I have multiple Docker images:
*myImage01.tar, myImage02.tar, myImage3.tar ...* so I want to load all those **images.tar** in the current path at the same time, instead of doing all one by one:

```
docker load -i myImage01.tar 
docker load -i myImage02.tar
docker load -i myImage03.tar
```

Is there any script/bash command to do so>?

Comment: `for i in \`ls *.tar\` ; do docker load -i $i ; done`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `*` in a `for` for this:

```
for filename in *; do
  docker load -i "$filename"
done
```